# return relationship data from database - xml, multi lines, other?

Tags: t-sql, architecture, c#-4.0

I have an web app which uses a DB for storage.
The code is C# there are two classes country and company.

The Company class contains a property with the relationship

List(Guid) CountryIds{get;private set}

The information is stored in the following manner in the db: 
Company
Company_Country
Country

An example query is:

```
select c.* , cc.CountryId
from Company c
   inner join Company_Country cc on c.id = cc.CompanyId
where (c.SomeColumn like 'somerestriction')
```

The question: What the most efficient way or even the current defacto standard to retrieve the relationship data from the database?

The options as I see it are:

1. use the above sql then in the c# code loop through the returned code adding the country id's to the correct company (very quick using a dictionary)
2. select the list of companies and then go back for each one with a separate sql query to get the list of country ids (simplest but big overhead to reconnect to the sql sever)
3. Use T-Sql to return the countryId in a xml format then use linq to extract the xml list from that comment (see sql below), note I would like to avoid delimited id strings.

Something like:

```
with cte(Id, CountryId) as 
(
select CompanyId, 
(SELECT CountryId as CountryId
    from Company_Country p2 
    WHERE p2.CompanyId = p1.CompanyId
    FOR XML PATH(''))  AS CountryId
from Company_Country p1
group by CompanyId
)

select ss.*, cte.countryid 
from StandardKitContent ss
    inner join cte on cte.id = ss.id
order by ss.id
```

4 Other? (please comment)

Many thanks
Choco

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a recent version of .NET, I recommend Entity Framework; it will slurp up your database tables, identify the relationships (if not automatically, then you can specify them in the designer or XML definition). Once that's done, it will generate business objects which will accurately reflect them, and you'll be able to do CRUD operations to your objects and have them persisted to your database.

Good luck!

Comment: hey thanks, we are using the latest version. I have always been skeptical of losing control over my database to dataaccess layers but it seems that soon I might have to relinquish to the reigns of modern design. :)

Comment: You do have some control over data access with EF (for example, specifying Views or Sprocs it will call instead of dynamic SQL).